# Is the variance of the mean of a set of independent random variables equal to the average of their respective variances?

Tags: variance, mean, random-variable, standard-deviation

I understand that, given a set of iid random variables, the variance of the sum is equal to the sum of the variance. Likewise, I know that the variance of the mean is equal to the variance over n.

My question is: if the variances of the respective random variables are not the same, is the variance of the mean still an average of the variances?

Comment: Do the variables have the same mean, even if they have different variances?

Comment: @Dave - that should not matter if the sample made up of one observation of each of the independent random variables

Comment: "Is the variance of the mean of a set of independent random variables equal to the average of their respective variances?" No. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Properties

Answer (score 7):

Given a set of random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$, if they are independent, then
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(\overline X) &= \text{Var}\left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\text{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}\left(X_i\right)
\end{align}
So the variance of the sample mean is equal to the mean of the variances divided by $n$, regardless of whether the variances are equal or not.

Comment: +1 though I think  you should "is equal to the mean of the variances divided by $n$" without "sample"

Comment: @Henry I used the word "sample" to differentiate it from the "population" mean $E[\cdot]$

Comment: OK, though I would say $\text{Var}\left(X_i\right)$ is one of the $n$ variances and $\frac1n\text{Var}\left(X_i\right)$ is the mean of the $n$ variances, without any sample or expectation involved

Comment: @Henry I’m not sure what you mean by “$\frac1n\text{Var}\left(X_i\right)$ is the mean of the $n$ variances”. What I mean by “sample mean of the variances” is $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}\left(X_i\right)$$ Is this what you were asking about?

Comment: @Henry actually, I just realized that what you meant is that if the variances are equal, then $$\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}\left(X_i\right) = \frac{1}{n} \text{Var}(X_i)$$ right?

Comment: I missed a summation sign - sorry -  and had intended to say "$\frac1n\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\text{Var}\left(X_i\right)$ is the mean of the $n$ variances, without any sample or expectation involved"

Comment: @mhdadk Basically (well, this may be a little nitpicking but I agree with Henry's pov), the wording "sample mean of the variances" is not correct -- because "variances" are non-random quantities, not a sample.  It is less ambiguous to say "arithmetic mean of variances" or just "mean of variances".

Comment: @Zhanxiong thanks for the explanation. Edited.